# write a file and send it to user

Tags: php, download

trying to write html to file and open a file dialog box

for the user to save it

but nothing happen and there is no errors

any ideas ?

thank you

this is my code

```
<?php
    $css=$_POST['css'];
    $html=$_POST['html'];

      $handle = fopen("file.txt", "w");
        fwrite($handle, $html);
        fclose($handle);

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($handle));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($handle));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($handle);
        exit;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass file object here, this should be a valid file name

```
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.txt'));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're mixing two things in your code: filehandles and filenames. `fopen`, `fwrite` and `fclose` work with the former; `basename`, `filesize` and `readfile` - with the latter. As you seem to have the filename as a fixed string, it can be written like this:

```
$filename = "./file.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "w");
fwrite($handle, $html);
fclose($handle);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . basename($filename));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($filename);
```

Second, I admit I don't get what's the code for. It seems that you need to return some input to a user as a download, you don't have to create a file, then write to it, then read it back immediately after: this...

```
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($html));
echo $html;
```

... is quite sufficient: you don't need to read the file back, it's enough to echo its content (and with `fwrite('w')`, it's exactly the same as `$html` content).